# PHPStorm Code view split

Tags: php, split, line

I am a new user of PHP Storm editor. I am not sure why there is a vertical line on my code view as seen on this image

[image]

http://screenshots.x10.mx/aHOWxR.jpg

I have reviewed their HELP section but can't find anything related to this vertical line.
Anyone know how to remove it as it is disturbing

Comment: I assume you googled [phpstorm code split view](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Settings, and under Editor -> General settings choose Appearance, then uncheck the box "Show right margin".

Answer (score 1):

The line displays where your ideal maximum line length ends (default 80 characters). If your line is longer and you use auto-formatting, it will add a linebreak to shorten your line.
I wouldn't remove the line because it helps you to keep your code clear (using shorter lines). You can adapt the ideal line length like you need it in the settings.